# Canbus communication not working without reset my data senders stm32s

Tags: stm32, can-bus

I have a problem with canbus communication in stm32. Actually, my communication works properly, but if I energize my cards at the same time, it stops working. Then, when I reset my data sending cards, I see that the problem is resolved and I start to receive data. What could be the cause of this problem? how can i solve it?

The leds I set for communication should light up.
I can't 'sometimes' receive data when first powered on.
but when I reset the data sending cards, I start to receive data and it works fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If one node is very slow at starting, to the point where the other node as alone on the bus long enough to enter error modes, then that will cause such problems. The common solution to this problem is no never leave nodes in error active/passive states but instead reset them (by writing an incorrect COP sequence etc) whenever such problems happen.